# Apex Compare UserInfo.getUserName() to a custom lookup Contact Field Name

Tags: apex, soql

EDIT: I am not receiving any error messages, it's just that the records I'm expecting to appear in the list are not showing up.

I need my controller to filter records to show only those where the logged in user Name matches the customer lookup field called Assigned To. Assigned to is a lookup to a Contact Record so it is not a User record.

Below is a snip of my controller.  I have included Assignedto__r.Name in my list of fields and and also queried the logged in user name. Below this you will see in my class that I made sure that Assignedto__r.Name is a String so they should be comparable, but I'm not getting the desired results.

Any help as to where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

```
public inherited sharing class pmListController {
@testVisible
private static List<String> projectFields = new List<String>{
    'Name',
    'Opportunity_Formula__c',
    'Opportunity__c',
    'Account_PK__c',
    'Status__c',
    'Action_Type__c',
    'Order_Submitted__c',
    'Tentative_Due_Date__c',
    'Confirmed_Due_Date__c',
    'Confirmed_Telexperts_Install_Date_Formul__c',
    'Carrier_Ref__c',
    'Assignedto__r.Name'
};


@AuraEnabled
public static string getAllData(){
    try {
        Id loggedInUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        String loggedInUserName = UserInfo.getUserName();
        String query = '';
        List<pmListColumns> rows = new List<pmListColumns>();
        
        query = 'SELECT ' + String.join(projectFields, ',') + ' FROM OrderProject__c  WHERE Assignedto__r.Name = :loggedInUserName AND Status__c NOT IN ( \'Cancelled\', \'Completed\')';
        List<OrderProject__c> pms = Database.query(query);
        for(OrderProject__c pm : pms) {
            rows.add(new pmListColumns(pm));
```

MY CLASS

```
public inherited sharing class pmListColumns {
//Common Fields
public Id id {get; set;}
public String name {get; set;}
public String type {get; set;}
public String opportunity {get; set;}
public String PK {get; set;}
public String status {get; set;}

//Project Fields
public String action {get; set;}
public Date carrierOrderSubmitted {get; set;}
public Date requestedCarrierDate {get; set;}
public Date confirmedCarrierDate {get; set;}
public Date confirmedTelexpertsInstallDate {get; set;}
public String carrierRef {get; set;}
public String assignedTo {get; set;}
//public String lastMilestone {get; set;}



public pmListColumns(OrderProject__c pm){
    this.type = 'Project';
    this.name = pm.Name;
    this.id = pm.Id;
    this.opportunity = pm.Opportunity_Formula__c;
    this.PK = pm.Account_PK__c;
    this.status = pm.Status__c;
    this.action = pm.Action_Type__c;
    this.carrierOrderSubmitted = pm.Order_Submitted__c;
    this.requestedCarrierDate = pm.Tentative_Due_Date__c;
    this.confirmedCarrierDate = pm.Confirmed_Due_Date__c;
    this.confirmedTelexpertsInstallDate = pm.Confirmed_Telexperts_Install_Date_Formul__c;
    this.carrierRef = pm.Carrier_Ref__c;
    this.assignedTo = pm.Assignedto__r.Name;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange. You state that you are "not getting the desired results." It would helpful to those who want to help you if you could please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/344978/edit) your question to include what results you _are_ getting - if it is an error, please include the exact error; if it is not an error but something does happen, include what happens; if nothing discernible happens, include that information. | Have you tried adding any debug statements?

Comment: @Moonpie thanks for the tip!  I've added an edit stating I wasn't receiving any error messages, just that the desired record wasn't showing up.  I was calling the wrong field from the User account, like a fool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UserInfo.getUserName()` doesn't get the User's Name. It gets the User's UserName. What you need is `UserInfo.getName()`.

Comment: Thank you! Sad thing is I stared at the Salesforce get user info options a couple of times to validate I had entered it correctly, but never considered I was looking at the wrong thing.  This fixed my problem.